# Synchronizing C code with ALSA

Tags: c, linux, audio, raspberry-pi, alsa

I am generating sound samples on the fly with C.  OS is Linux.  Hardware is Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.  I need to write the generated samples to the circular buffer synchronized to the sample rate.  ALSA seems quite sophisticated, so I imagine there is a flag or something that I can use to be sure I don't overrun or underrun the buffer.  So, if I am using 48000 samples per second I want to generate the next sample and write it 1/48000th of a second after the last sample was written.  Suggestions appreciated, as well as references to good ALSA docs.

Comment: It appears that there are more answer on some other forums. Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74558/change-sampling-rate-in-alsa

Answer (score 1):

To prevent underruns, you should try to keep the buffer as full as possible at all times.

This happens automatically when the device is in the (default) blocking mode: when you try to write samples, but the ring buffer is full, the function sleeps until some space has become available. So just try to write samples as fast as possible.